# Contours in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

I have drawn a circle on my image, and I want to find any points where the circle and a specific contour intersect.

How would I go about finding the intersecting points between a contour and a circle?

Thanks

Comment: Is the contour drawn on the circle or you just have it stored in a CvSeq?

Comment: Its just stored in a CvSeq. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is an idea of how you could do it:

If you know the center of the circle and the radius, also if the contour that you have is obtained with `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE :
Translates all the points from the chain code into points.` 
then you can simply go through all the points of the sequence and see which ones have a distance from the center of the circle equal to the radius.(there can be more than 2 intersections)

If your contour is not obtained with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE then you can check each pair of 2 points in the sequence and process the ones that have one outside(distance higher than radius) and one inside(distance lower than radius) or maybe on the circle(lucky case). Then you will know that the intersection point is between those 2 points and you can find it by solving the 2 equation system:

-point is on the line constructed by the 2 points

-point is at a distance from the center of the circle equal to the radius

If by any chance you don't know where the circle is or it's radius than you can get it's contour with `cvFindContours` and then go through each set of 2 points from the other contour and use :

```
    double cvPointPolygonTest(
                  const CvArr* contour,
                  CvPoint2D32f pt,
                  int measure_dist
                  );
```

In particular, if the argument measure_dist is nonzero then the function returns
the distance to the nearest contour edge; that distance is 0 if the point is inside the
contour and positive if the point is outside. If the measure_dist argument is 0 then the
return values are simply + 1, – 1, or 0 depending on whether the point is inside, outside,
or on an edge (or vertex), respectively. Th e contour itself can be either a sequence or an
n-by-1 two-channel matrix of points.

From this you get 2 points, one outside, one inside or on the circle, and the distances of each to the circle. Again, enough info to compute the exact point.

PS: You can optimize the algorithm by first checking if the bounding rectangles of the 2 contours at least intersect. You can get these with `cvMinAreaRect2`

Comment: @user1017485: why not voting up then? (+1) thanks for explanation!